# How do I use a Droboshare over a wireless connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, drobo, droboshare

I'm using Drobo with DroboShare, and the DroboShare is connected to my wifi routeur (Bbox provided by French ISP Bouygues) via an ethernet cable.

I can access Drobo from my PC if I use an ethernet connection to the wifi routeur, but I cannot access it directly via wifi.

How shall I set this up?

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure your router is giving IPs in the same range to the wifi and wired clients. For example is the wired interface getting 192.168.x.x and the Wireless getting something else?